# Function to select value from data frame based on value in list of lists

Tags: r, function

In R I need to write a function that applies the following rules:

```
fkt <- function(v1,v2){
    - find list name within listOfLists that contains v1       
    - go to column in df, where listname == colname  
    - return value from row where df$col2 == v2

}
```

For Example:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1= c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   Col2= c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE"),
                   A = c("22","22","23","23","24"),
                   B = c("210","210","202","220","203"),
                   C = c("2000","2000","2010","2010","2200")
                   )



listOflists <- list(A <- c(1281, 1282, 1285, 1286, 1289),
                    B <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,101,202,303,404,505,606),
                    C <-c(1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3050,4000,4500,6000)
)
```

Then

```
fkt(800,"BBB") 
> 210
```

I tried

```
fkt<- function(v1,v2){
      r <- which(df$Col2== v1)
      s <- ifelse(v2 %in% A, df$A[r], 
                 ifelse( v2 %in% B ,df$A[r],df$C[r]))
  return(s)
}
```

Alas, the result is NA.
And writing many ifelse() statements is not efficient - especially because the listOfLists might comprise >50 lists.

Can anyone advice me how to write this function in a general, programming efficient way as described above?

Comment: If each `v1` is only contained in a single list in `listOfLists`, you seem to be using the wrong data structure. Perhaps you can replace `listOfLists` by a 2-column dataframe where 1 column consists of the numbers `1281`, etc. (possible values of `v1`) and the other columns consist of column names `"A"`, `"B"`, etc.). It is easier to search for something in a flat data structure than a nested data structure. It would be easy enough to write a function which transforms your `listOfLists` into such a dataframe.

Comment: FYI, your `listOflists` is **not** a list of lists. It is a list of vectors.

Comment: To make a list of vectors (thanks for correcting me) have different length - so data frame seemed not ideal. A 2-column dataframe is easy enough. Thanks a lot of this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Col1= c(1,2,3,4,5),
               Col2= c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE"),
               A = c("22","22","23","23","24"),
               B = c("210","210","202","220","203"),
               C = c("2000","2000","2010","2010","2200"))
# Be cautious : = and <- are not equivalent, you were creating variables not named fields
listOflists <- list(A = c(1281, 1282, 1285, 1286, 1289),
                    B = c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,101,202,303,404,505,606),
                    C = c(1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3050,4000,4500,6000))

f <- function(v1) 
  for (i in 1:length(listOflists)) 
    if (v1 %in% listOflists[[i]]) return(names(listOflists)[i])

fkt <- function(v1,v2) df[df$Col2==v2,f(v1)]

fkt(800,"BBB")
#[1] 210
#Levels: 202 203 210 220
```

Comment: Good catch on `<-` vs `=` in this context. The names are simply dropped in OP's `listOfLists` (+1)

Comment: Thank you so much for both catching my mistake with <-, and providing an elegant solution. Really much appreciated!